# SQL How to filter based on logic JOIN

Tags: sql-server

I have a query with a join:

```
....
JOIN 
    Permission up ON up.PermissionID = c.PermissionID 
                  AND (@IsUserAdmin = 1 AND up.EmployeeID = @EmployeeID)
....
```

I just want to apply the `EmployeeID` filter if `@IsUserAdmin` is 1.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a `case` expression to do this like so:

```
join Permission up 
  on up.PermissionID =c.PermissionID 
  and up.EmployeeId = case 
    when @IsUserAdmin = 1 
      then @EmployeeID
    else up.EmployeeId
    end
```

The `case` expression basically says if `@IsUserAdmin = 1` then `up.EmployeeId` must equal `@EmployeeId` else `up.EmployeeId` must equal `up.EmployeeId`.

If `up.EmployeeId` is nullable, you would wrap both `up.EmployeeId`references in an `isnull(up.EmployeeId,0)` or `coalesce(up.EmployeeId,0)` to allow it to evaluate as equal.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is `INNER JOIN`, the filters that don't involve both joined tables are better be moved to the `WHERE` clause. The engine doesn't care, but it just makes the query more readable to programmers.

```
...
JOIN Permission up ON up.PermissionID = c.PermissionID
...
WHERE
(up.EmployeeID = @EmployeeID OR @IsUserAdmin <> 1)
...
OPTION(RECOMPILE);
```

If `@IsUserAdmin` is not 1, then the value of `@EmployeeID` doesn't matter.

If `@IsUserAdmin` is 1, then the value of `@EmployeeID` will be used in the filter.

This type of queries is discussed in great detail in [Dynamic Search Conditions in T‑SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2008.html) by Erland Sommarskog. He explains there why you usually want to add `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` for this type of query.

Answer (score -1):

Use a where statement after you join it.

Or instead of writing Permission up
Try this

( Select * from permission up 
where EmployeeID=@IsUserAdmin)

Comment: `EmployeedID` != `@IsUserAdmin`.  the latter is a boolean/bit...  however, moving the clause to the `where` statement should work.